# I am not able to get data from api in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I am trying to get data from my Django rest API in Angular Universal for server-side rendering. But instead, I am getting

> 304 Request ( Not Modified )

I have seen in many other examples as well that their code is working well and even api requests are working but I could not understand where I am going wrong here.

I am attaching all the required files here. Thanks for any help

server.ts

```js
import 'zone.js/node';

const domino = require("domino");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const templateA = fs
  .readFileSync(path.join("dist/browser", "index.html"))
  .toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(templateA);
win.Object = Object;
win.Math = Math;

global["window"] = win;
global["document"] = win.document;
``
import 'localstorage-polyfill'

global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

import {
  APP_BASE_HREF
} from '@angular/common';
import {
  ngExpressEngine
} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import {
  existsSync
} from 'fs';
import {
  join
} from 'path';
import {
  AppServerModule
} from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      providers: [{
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useValue: req.baseUrl
      }]
    });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare
const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "dealfront",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run offer-buzzar:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/offer-buzzar/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run offer-buzzar:server",
    "prerender": "ng run offer-buzzar:prerender",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~15.2.9",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.2.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "katex": "^0.13.11",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^15.0.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^20.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-emoji": "^0.2.0",
    "quill-image-resize": "^3.0.9",
    "quill-image-resize-module": "^3.0.0",
    "quill-mention": "^2.2.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.1",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.2.9",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^15.2.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@types/quill": "1.3.10",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

Component where I am making api call:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.api.getPopularMerchants().subscribe(merchantList => {
      this.merchantTODisplay = merchantList.results
    })
  }
```

Interceptor service

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {
    const token: any = this.accessToken;
    if (token && this.isTokenRequired(request)) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }

  isTokenRequired(request: any) {
    const url = request.url;
    if ((url.includes('auth/users/me/') || url.includes('votes')) || url.includes('auth/users/set_email/') || url.includes('info') || url.includes('auth/users/set_password/') ||
      ((url.includes('deals') || url.includes('vouchers')) && (request.method === 'POST' || request.method === 'PUT' || request.method === 'DELETE'))) {
      return true;
    }
    if (url.includes('status=') && (request.method === 'GET')) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  get accessToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('access');
  }

}
```

Api service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  prefix: string = "api/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.prefix = environment.API_URL_PREFIX;
  }
  getPopularMerchants(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.prefix + 'merchants/?limit=10&o=-score');
  }
  
}
```

Comment: On my live environment AJAX calls during SSR don't work anyway, since they're being blocked. I have to explicitly pass the data to angular during SSR. But it's a little complicated to explain here. [Here's](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/merge/release/2.1-to-release/3.1/src/Middleware/SpaServices.Extensions/src/Prerendering) the original source code. [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices) what I made of it. And [here's](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/server-side-rendering-ssr-under-the-hood-asp-net-core-51562b70e511) an attempt to explain